# Reproducible checksum .so file on different machine

Tags: gcc, distcc

i'm trying to generate a shared library with the same checksum on two different machines (source code, Linux OS, gcc, cmake, ccache, g++ have same version. Only hardware change).

I tried `-frandom-seed=string` flag but impossible to have the same checksum ...

Is there a way to make it possible ?

Thanks very much.

Sylvain

Comment: Can you tell us which checksum generator you're using?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using **cmake** to build your project then to have a same checksums on two different servers , you should  add a command to your Makefile.txt that generates a shared object/library/executable. Actually, Cmake does not guarantee a consistent linking order of the object files unless we explicitly sort them.
To do so, call list:

```
list(SORT <variable>)
```

For example, the following command will sort the files in the variable `SRC_FILE`, which are then used to generate the shared library/object:

```
list(SORT SRC_FILES)
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${HEADER_FILES} ${SRC_FILES})
```

Thanks

Comment: Correction :  it's  list(SORT SRC_FILES)